# Resizing columns in a QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, width, qtablewidget

I'm developing a C++ Qt application that uses `QTableWidget` to show data.

As far as I know, `QTableWidget` provides automatic resizing mode for columns: resize the last one.

This approach didn't fit for my task, so I wrote the new class inherited from `QTableWidget` with `resizeEvent` function:

```
MyTableWidget::MyTableWidget ( std::vector<int> columnsRelWidth )
{
    //columnsRelWidth contains relative width of each column in the table

    this->columnWidth = columnsRelWidth;
}

void MyTableWidget::resizeEvent ( QResizeEvent *event )
{
    QSize newSize = event->size();
    int totalPoints = 0; //total points of relative width
    for ( int x = 0; x < this->columnWidth.size(); ++x )
    {
        totalPoints += this->columnWidth[x];
    }
    int width = newSize.width();
    double point = width / totalPoints; //one point of relative width in px
    for ( int x = 0; x < this->columnCount(); ++x )
    {
        this->setColumnWidth ( x, ( this->columnWidth[x] * point ) );
    }
}
```

I added 4 columns and set the following relative width values (their sum is **1000**):

```
| First column | Second column | Third column | Fourth column |
|     100      |      140      |     380      |      380      |
```

Nevertheless, I can't see any columns in the table until table's width is less that **1000**.
Using debug mode, I saw that variable `point` equals to **0** if `width < totalPoints` is true. For example, if `width` equals to **762**, `point` should be **0.762**, but it is **0**.

It looks like program automatically rounds `double` value. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Maybe there are better ways to accomplish my task (use percent columns width in `QTableWidget`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `width` and `totalPoints` are integers. So you get an integer division there, and that will result in zero whenever `width < totalPoints`.

Cast one of them to `double`:

```
double point = width / (double) totalPoints;
```